# I got value error while training my GAN such as: "ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([10, 1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([10]))"

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am new at GANs and also pytorch, studied some repos to developed my skills, but when I tried to implement this repo:

```
https://github.com/jasonbian97/Deep-Learning-Computer-Vision/blob/master/generative_adversarial_networks.ipynb
```

Everything goes well, but I got such error when I tried to change these code snippets in
def discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake) function
(I changed it because before this change I got ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([128])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([128, 1])) ):

```
  logits_real_loss = bce_loss(logits_real, torch.ones(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))
  logits_fake_loss = bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.zeros(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))
  loss = logits_real_loss + logits_fake_loss
```

and

```
  N = logits_fake.shape[0]
  device = logits_fake.device
  loss = (bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.ones(N,1).to(dtype).to(device)))
```

Getting value error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-15-b089f365cd5e> in <module>()
      2   d_loss = discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)
      3   print("Maximum error in d_loss: %g"%rel_error(d_loss_true, d_loss))
----> 4 test_discriminator_loss(answers['logits_real'], answers['logits_fake'],answers['d_loss_true'])

2 frames

<ipython-input-15-b089f365cd5e> in test_discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake, d_loss_true)
      1 def test_discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake, d_loss_true):
----> 2   d_loss = discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)
      3   print("Maximum error in d_loss: %g"%rel_error(d_loss_true, d_loss))
      4 test_discriminator_loss(answers['logits_real'], answers['logits_fake'],answers['d_loss_true'])

<ipython-input-14-15d437ae3425> in discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)
     17   N = logits_real.shape[0]
     18   device = logits_real.device
---> 19   logits_real_loss = bce_loss(logits_real, torch.ones(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))
     20   logits_fake_loss = bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.zeros(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))
     21   loss = logits_real_loss + logits_fake_loss

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)
   2578 
   2579     if not (target.size() == input.size()):
-> 2580         raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
   2581 
   2582     return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)

ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([10, 1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([10]))
```

Maybe solution is so simple, but I cannot see could anyone help me for fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

*As much context wasn't given, so can't be sure If It's gonna solve your issue.*

From the information given, It looks like the issue is with the dissimilar shape of tensors you're sending as parameters in your loss function. Your input loss's dimension is `[10]`, however the other tensor you're sending's `[N,1] => [10,1]` dimensional. So to quickly recover from the issue you could just do something like this-

`torch.zeros(N).to(dtype).to(device)`

which will make your tensor shape `[N] => [10]`, same as the input.